# маштабирование iframe с видео

Tags: html, css, iframe

День добрый! Возникла проблема с маштабированием окна. Есть два примера, в первом маштабируется только видео во втором полностью окно, разница в теге 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,user-scalable=no" />` в первом есть, во втором нету. Кто сможет подсказать почему так происходит.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body>
 <div style="overflow-y: auto; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 100%;">
  <div style="margin: 5px; white-space: normal; text-align: right;">
   <font size="2" face="Trebuchet MS" color="#000000" hyphens="auto">01.01.2001 6 месяцев</font>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div style="overflow-y: auto; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 100%;">
  <div style="margin: 5px; white-space: normal; text-align: center;">
   <font size="4" face="Trebuchet MS" color="#000000" hyphens="auto">Программа для распознания альпинистских маршрутов</font>
  </div>
 </div> 
 <div style="margin: 5px; white-space: normal; text-align: left;">
  <font size="4" face="Trebuchet MS" color="#000000" hyphens="auto">Начать?!? Наверно надо начать с того что это описание я пишу через 10 лет, и когда то я был не силен в программировании и вообще в IT. Сейчас открывая приложения я посмеялся над ляпами и моими замахами на то время. Но подобное вообще появилось лет так этак через 8, что то типа:<
  br><br>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rl-Eg21TqsA<br><br>(это один из примеров), но суть примера такая же, только я ее придумал и сделал 10 лет назад. Ну на счет сделал это наверно громко сказано, но основные моменты по поднятию высот и склейки получиных мешей (тогда я даже не знал что такое меш и даже не знал что есть такой редактор как 3DMax)))) Я сам делал себе редактор и он там как то совсем уж плохо сливал, подгонял, там файлы были по 200 метров, все в формате bmp, там на сколько я помню даже классов всего было 3 причем один, мего божественный))) Но я все равно люблю этот проект, так как именно благодаря ему я стал тем кем я стал. <br><br>Суть проекта сводилась к довольно простой логике, требовалось сделать N-количество снимков и привязать их к jps координатам. 
 </font>
</div>
</div>
 <div style="overflow-y: auto; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: flex; white-space: nowrap; justify-content: center;">
  <div style="width: 620px; height: 480px; flex-basis: 620px; flex-shrink: 1;">
   <iframe frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pTpqrzGF5Hw" style="margin: 5px; width: 90%; height: 95%;">
    
   </iframe>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>uptask3d</title>

</head>

<body >
  <div style="overflow-y: auto; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 100%;">
  <div style="margin: 5px; white-space: normal; text-align: right;">
   <font size="2" face="Trebuchet MS" color="#000000" hyphens="auto">01.01.2001 6 месяцев</font>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div style="overflow-y: auto; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 100%;">
  <div style="margin: 5px; white-space: normal; text-align: center;">
   <font size="4" face="Trebuchet MS" color="#000000" hyphens="auto">Программа для распознания альпинистских маршрутов</font>
  </div>
 </div> 
 <div style="margin: 5px; white-space: normal; text-align: left;">
  <font size="4" face="Trebuchet MS" color="#000000" hyphens="auto">Начать?!? Наверно надо начать с того что это описание я пишу через 10 лет, и когда то я был не силен в программировании и вообще в IT. Сейчас открывая приложения я посмеялся над ляпами и моими замахами на то время. Но подобное вообще появилось лет так этак через 8, что то типа:<
  br><br>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rl-Eg21TqsA<br><br>(это один из примеров), но суть примера такая же, только я ее придумал и сделал 10 лет назад. Ну на счет сделал это наверно громко сказано, но основные моменты по поднятию высот и склейки получиных мешей (тогда я даже не знал что такое меш и даже не знал что есть такой редактор как 3DMax)))) Я сам делал себе редактор и он там как то совсем уж плохо сливал, подгонял, там файлы были по 200 метров, все в формате bmp, там на сколько я помню даже классов всего было 3 причем один, мего божественный))) Но я все равно люблю этот проект, так как именно благодаря ему я стал тем кем я стал. <br><br>Суть проекта сводилась к довольно простой логике, требовалось сделать N-количество снимков и привязать их к jps координатам. 
 </font>
</div>
</div>

 <div style="overflow-y: auto; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: flex; white-space: nowrap; justify-content: center;">
  <div style="width: 620px; height: 480px; flex-basis: 620px; flex-shrink: 1;">
   <iframe frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pTpqrzGF5Hw" style="margin: 5px; width: 90%; height: 95%;">  
   </iframe>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Хотелось бы, чтоб эта страница нормально отображалась в мобильных телефонах. Потому что, во втором варианте где нормально маштабируется видео, при сужении экрана увеличивается текст

Answer (score 0):

Тег

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,user-scalable=no"/>
```

добавляет адаптивность странице. Для правильного масштабирования используйте `@media` и указанный выше тег.
[Здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) вы можете прочитать про использование @media запросов.